# Firestore rules: Allow access to a document using password

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to build a feature into my app to "share" data from one user to another. (Like sharing a Google Doc). I'm currently using Firebase Firestore for my database, and I don't have a server setup.

Both user A and user B have Firestore docs. Optimally, user A sends user B an airdrop or iMessage with a URI into my app. User B is greeted with a dialog to accept the request. Upon acceptance, both user A and user B can both read each others docs.

I was thinking of writing a URI something like this **myapp://share?password=123**, but I can't seem to figure out how to write the Firestore rules to accommodate it. The only ways I seem to be able to find to authenticate a user is through their UID or their email, but not through a password or other piece of secret information.

Is there a way to write Firestore rules to do this, or is there a better way to do this overall?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fake this kind of data flow by setting the password as a node in the path to the document itself, including the document. Just ensure that the document is using a unique path to prevent password clashes if you are using low grade passwords.

When User B accepts it from the client, you can update a key-value inside the document to a value of 'accepted' as `true` which you can use [Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) to allow users to read under certain conditions

Using rules to target specific read & write functionality

```js
allow get: if request.resource.data.accepted == true;
allow update: if request.data.accepted == true && 
 (request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(['accepted']));
```

Source:

- [Firestore Rules: Change certain fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-fields#allowing_only_certain_fields_to_be_changed)
- [Firestore Rules Properties](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do this is to:

1. name the Firestore document after the secret value,
2. only allow `get` in your security rules, not `list`.

So say that your password/secret is `correcthorsebatterystaple`. That means the document is also named `correcthorsebatterystaple`.

Now if you implement these rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document} {
      allow get: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

A user can only `get` a document if they know its ID, so in this case only if they know `correcthorsebatterystaple`.

Also see the Firebase documentation on [granular operations in security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations).