# Firebase allow users to access with a secret key

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I want to email users a link to submit feedback.

The link has an access key unique to each user.

User should be able to submit if the access key is valid.

How is this possible on Firebase?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do that is to:

1. Generate the key for each user.
2. Already create a (possibly empty) document with secret key as the document ID
3. Send the key to the user
4. Only allow the document to be updated, if that document already exists. So allow `update`, but not `create` from the [granular security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations).
5. Don't allow the user to `list` documents in the collection, although you can allow them to `get` them.

In step 2, you could also write the UID of the targeted user into the document and perform an extra check on that in your security rules.

Also see:

*
[Firestore rules: Allow access to a document using password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67443698/firestore-rules-allow-access-to-a-document-using-password/67443780#67443780)

Comment: This would mean I need to keep this doc in sync with the one it's giving feedback. Otherwise, I will have to do two reads every time I need to pull out feedback for a document.  -- 

How about, create a cloud function that validates the secret key and returns a custom JWT token encoding access rights that I validate in security rules. 

Does this make sense? -- 

this would require calling `signInWithCustomToken` on the app with a custom JWT token, that signs out existing sessions? is it possible to retain existing users sessions and pass the custom token?

Comment: I need to make sure this cloud function is only used by the app. Is CORS security sufficient here?

Comment: "This would mean I need to keep this doc in sync with the one it's giving feedback. Otherwise, I will have to do two reads every time I need to pull out feedback for a document." As far as I can tell the only read is the one the user does. Where do you see another one? Using Cloud Functions is probably also possible, but the approach I describe is pretty idiomatic and doesn't need a server-side component (you can run step 1-3 on your development machine if you want).

Comment: the feedback is given on a document. I want to show some document info on the feedback page only if they have the key.

Comment: Yes, that was the use-case you explained in your question. The approach in my answer is pretty idiomatic for implementing that without any server code. I recommend giving it a try.

Comment: @Surya Did you give this a try yet?