# Firebase - allow data access only with a token

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have a to-do list application where users need to sign up via Google and then they can create a todo-list. For that, I have just one collection **lists** and each list document has two fields **ownerId** and **items**.

Via security rules I've restricted the access just for the owner:

```
match /lists/{list}
   allow read, edit: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.ownerId;
```

Next, I want to extend it so owners can share their todo-list with other users by sending them a link to it.

I thought about adding a new field to **lists** collection called **accessToken** that I will generate when creating the list and they can then share **[www.myapp.com/join/{accessToken}](http://www.myapp.com/join/%7BaccessToken%7D)** to others.

My question is if it is possible to send a custom token to firestore and then check it in the rules like:

```
match /lists/{list}
   allow read, edit: if request.auth != null && request.{my_access_token} == resource.data.accessToken;
```

Or if there is some more elegant way to achieve this

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67443698/firestore-rules-allow-access-to-a-document-using-password/67443780#67443780 and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69956707/firebase-allow-users-to-access-with-a-secret-key?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen These look promising. Thank you!