# Most convenient way to use secret key based access in Firebase

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm writing React app using Firebase (Firestore and Storage) where I want to have following roles:

1. Authors - they create some content (Items, may be more than one per Author) that are shared with Reviewers. Only Author can initiate Item creation
2. Reviewers - they can receive link that allows them to read and review concrete Item sent by Author. Reviewer may read, add and modify (of course they can't delete everything, but that's not core of this post) its content.

My idea is to reflect above in following Firestore structure:

```
/users/{user_id}/items/{item_id}/<other_documents_and_collections_related_to_item>
```

To secure the access, I want to use security rules. For Authors rules are quite simple:

1. Author must be authenticated as a user
2. Author can read and write. Security rule compares author auth uid with item_id in document path.

Reviewer security rule is something I wanted to ask about. I wanted to make it as convenient for Reviewer as possible, so I wanted completely avoid need to register. I want to allow Author sending link via mail to Reviewer who can just use the link to access the data. On the other hand, I wouldn't like to allow everyone reading all Items of an Author by just knowing item_ids, so I need some kind of password/secret key for each Item to have basic protection.

My current idea is following:

1. During item creation, generate additional password/secret key and add it to {item_id} document
2. Pass secret key/password in link in mail sent to Reviewer
3. Reviewer clicks the link containing password/secret key
4. Password/secret key is stored for the current session of Reviewer and is used in security rules to allow access to concrete Item's data

To fulfil above scenario I need information about secret key at each Firebase call (to compare it with Item's secret key). Per my understanding there is no direct way to pass such param at every read/write call, thus I wanted to use auth variable. I found following solutions which are around it, but does not exactly do the job:

1. Using anonymousAuth - this one does not need registering, adds auth variable and can be reused, but is there a way to pass a parameter to auth variable used by security rules?
2. signInWithEmailLink - it delivers link that may be used to login, but per my understanding it still needs to create an account, doesn't it? Also it adds security mechanisms to prevent reuse which I don't want to handle.
3. Add Custom Claim to Auth - this solution sounds perfect, but it needs Admin SDK and another server that will work as backend. I want rely fully on Firebase and do not use any additional backend server.

Is there another way to do that? I considered creating additional user for each Item with dummy mail and password and pass that in a link, but that sounds terrible.

P.S. Data I want to expose may be publicly available, so potential leak of the secret key is not a big deal. Its aim is just to limit such possibility.

---- Added after @FrankvanPuffelen's comment

After rethinking I see an option here: I can indeed add additional document with id equal to secret key under Item main document (cons: it would have to be in collection that would always contain only 1 element). Additionally I can add document with known name under Item document that contains secret key as a field. Access to document containing secret key is allowed only for Author. Summing up it would look like this:

```
/users/{user_id}/items/{item_id}/secrets/{secret_key}/<other_documents_and_collections_related_to_item>
/users/{user_id}/items/{item_id}/privates/sec_key <- this document contains secret_key as a field
```

Security rules would have to block access to sec_key document and listing secrets collection for users other than Author. Also security rules for all the writes (performed by non-Author user) done under

```
/users/{user_id}/items/{item_id}/secrets/{secret_key}/**
```

would have to check if above document exists.

With above changes Author user could always read secret from sec_doc and use it to build correct path containing secret whereas Reviewer user would have to use delivered secret_key to build path for all the operations (as he cannot read it from sec_key doc and all the writes would check existance of path containing secret_key first).

Drawback is all Reviewer calls cost additional exists() operation.

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69956707/firebase-allow-users-to-access-with-a-secret-key and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67443698/firestore-rules-allow-access-to-a-document-using-password/67443780#67443780?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, I did, but there are two problems:
1) it adds another object to the tree which seems redundant, especially that projectId itself is unique id generated by Firebase and thus knowing it can be assumed as some kind of knowing secret
2) presented example shows acces to single document whereas my example is more complicated - under main Item document there will be multiple subcollections and some of them will need list functionality (e. g. fetching all comments that will have to be in collection). I assume there is no way to use this patterin in such scenario.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @delcree, please post your edit as an answer if you have resolved it so that other community members with similar questions could benefit from it.