# How to send a custom token to firebase when deleting a document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I need to send a **custom token** to firebase when I **delete a document** to validate the token in the **firestore rules**.

I already tried to send the token in the solition header, like this:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getFirestore, doc, setDoc, deleteDoc } from 'firebase/firestore'

const config = {
    ...
}

const app = initializeApp(config)
console.log(app)

const db = getFirestore(app, {
    customHeaders: {
        { "content-Type": "application/json"
    }
})

function deleteTest() {
    console.info('Deletion started')
    const documentToExclude = doc(db, 'advertisers', 'vanortton1676727765248');
    const config = {
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer delete@C0n53d3d3#'
        }
    };
    deleteDoc(documentToDelete, config)
        .then(() => {
            console.log('Document deleted successfully!')
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error deleting document:', error);
        });
}

deleteTest()
```

And that was my rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /advertisers/{docId} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow delete: if tokenValid();
    }
    function tokenValido() {
       return request.auth.token == 'Bearer delete@C0n53d3d3#';
    }
  }
}
```

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic mapping from `Authorization` headers into the token in Firebase security rules. If you want to pass a value like that, you'll have to encode it into the user's ID token as a [custom claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims).

More feasible might be to to write the document ID and user ID into the database, and then check *that* combination in the security rules - without passing any extra information in the request.

Alternatively, you can pass the information needed in the path to the document as shown here: [Firestore rules: Allow access to a document using password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67443698/firestore-rules-allow-access-to-a-document-using-password), but I'm not sure if that'd apply to this use-case.

Comment: Is there any way to create a custom login in firebase?
I created a login method that only allows one user to log in, admin, is there any way to log into firebase passing a custom token?
Note: My application is made in electron

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens